# Spring Data: Connect to Cassandra via SSL

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I want to connect to a Cassandra Cluster via SSL from a Java application using Spring Data. We have the following script which successfully connects to the cluster. Basically, it only enables SSL connection without specifying the SSL certificate.

```
mkdir .cassandra
echo "[ssl]" > .cassandra/cqlshrc
echo "validate = false" >> .cassandra/cqlshrc
cqlsh -u USER -p PASS -k KEYSPACE --debug --ssl HOSTNAME
```

I tried to set up the same connection options in a Spring @Configuration , via a CassandraClusterFactoryBean. Here is the snippet in question:

```
CassandraClusterFactoryBean factoryBean = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();        
factoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoint);
factoryBean.setPort(9042);
factoryBean.setQueryOptions(queryOptions); 
factoryBean.setAuthProvider(cassandraAuthentication());          
factoryBean.setSslEnabled(true);
```

The `cassandraAuthentication()` method creates an `AuthProvider` with plaintext credentials.  Upon trying to connect to the cluster I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: <hostname>:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [<hostname>:9042] Error writing))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:268) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:107) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1652) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1571) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:208) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:376) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:332) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.connect(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:89) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:59) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

What settings should I add in the cluster configuration to be able to connect to the database? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  CassandraClusterFactoryBean use below code,

```
@Bean
@Override
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean(); 
    PlainTextAuthProvider sap = new PlainTextAuthProvider(env.getProperty("cassandra.username"), env.getProperty("cassandra.password"));
    cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
    cluster.setAuthProvider(sap);
    return cluster;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, since the Cassandra server accepts only SSL connections

Comment: If ssl is enable in your Cassandra cluster then you need to use only ssl connection

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean @Override public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean(); 
    PlainTextAuthProvider sap = new PlainTextAuthProvider(env.getProperty("cassandra.username"), env.getProperty("cassandra.password"));
    cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
    cluster.setAuthProvider(sap);
    cluster.setSslEnabled(true);
    return cluster; }
```

Quoted from the original answer by @soUvIk and added `cluster.setSslEnabled(true);`to try connecting with sssl.